# Downvoting opinions?

Tags: voting, discussion

Simple. Someone shares their opinion about a topic and is making it's clear it's just an opinion, not an answer. (Then again, opinions are a kind of answer too.)
Now, would it be okay to downvote opinions when I disagree with them or not? In my opinion, downvoting should be done to show the bad answers. But an opinion can't be bad, since it's just an opinion. Just like an opinion can't be good and thus we shouldn't upvote either.

This is just my opinion, btw. If you agree or disagree, leace a comment. Don't vote for this one! ;-)

Comment: -1 I disagree---If a question calls for an opinion, voting is there for stating wether you agree or not (esp. on MSO).

Comment: Also, questions calling for opinions and answers stating such are usually CWed, so that it's clear that a downvote is not a punishment (On MSO, this happens less often than on SO. But then again, rep doesn't mean much on MSO).

Comment: In my opinion, leace is not a good word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are we talking about Meta or SO (or another site)? Is this an opinion which actually has technical impact and could lead someone down a path you think is going to cause problems?

- On Meta, downvotes are *often* used as "I don't like this idea" which seems pretty reasonable. Meta is almost entirely subjective anyway.
- On SO, I'd be more reluctant to downvote in this way. A comment explaining the disagreement would normally be fine.
- If it's an "opinion" which gives misleading information ("In my opinion, Java passes objects by reference") or which could be deeply damaging then I think it's reasonable to downvote. Still leave a comment though.
- On SU and SF I don't know what the conventions are. I'd expect SF to be mostly like SO, and SU to be somewhere between SO and Meta.

Answer (score 3):

I am more inclined to downvote an opinion if I not only disagree with it, but *violently* disagree with it. This happens, but it's ... rare.

So I'd say feel free to downvote but only when you feel very, very strongly that it is necessary. I would discourage people from casual downvoting whenever possible.

Comment: ***shocked*** There is only rare instances where you disagree with an opinion? :)

Comment: if I violently disagree with something on S[OFU] the odds are it's a bad question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Why the hate for down votes? (sarcasm)

Opinions may not be *'wrong'* in your strictly defined context, but they certainly can be  uninformed, irrelevant, or just plain asinine.  Let the down votes flow.